# How can I get the instance of the caller instance dynamically using reflection

Tags: java, swing, inheritance, reflection

I am working in a Swing application.

```
public class Owner extends JPanel{
  Child child=null;
  public Owner(){
   child=new Child();
  }
}

public  class Child extends JPanel{
   public Child(){
     // Here I want the instance of Owner class.
     // This child class is being created from many classes(almost 1000) like the Owner class.
   }
}
```

I want some way to get the instance of the calling class instance, maybe using reflection.
So that I can associate a `KeyListener` to each instance.
This is required, otherwise I have to write the same codes in all the 1000 classes.

All my classes are extending `JPanel`, I can get the parent from the `Parent` property once the component is associated to the component to the parent. But here I need it inside the constructor of `Child`, i.e. the component is not associated to `Owner` yet.

Comment: It seems the design is SNAFU, given extending panels & the need to access the parent from within a constructor.

Comment: "How to pass a parameter to a constructor" is your question ? Or "how can i reuse the code between my 1000 classes" ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public class Owner extends JPanel{
 Child child=null;
 public Owner(){
 child=new Child(this);
 }
}

public  class Child extends JPanel{
    Object owner ;
    public Child(Object owner ){
       this.owner = owner ;
      // Here I want the instance of Owner class.
      // This child class is being created from many classes(almost 1000) like the       Owner class.
    }
 }
```

Comment: I don't want to change any of my 1000 classes.

Comment: I don't want to change any of my 1000 classes(All are view files).My intention is to get the main view instance from which it is being instantiated (these code are already there), and then I will associate a key listener to that view from this child class.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that may help you:

```
public class Owner extends JPanel {
    Child child;

    public Owner() {
        child = new Child(this);
    }
}

public class Child extends JPanel {
    Owner owner;

    public Child(Owner owner) {
        this.owner = owner;
        // add key listeners here to owner
        owner.addKeyListener(...)
    }
}
```